# How to make 3-Column layout with fluid center without floats

Tags: css

I am trying to create a three column layout, with static width sidebars, and a fluid center column. I do NOT want the columns dropping when the page gets too narrow (center column at 250px), I'd like to have the whole thing just freeze, and employ side scrolling. Pretty sure this can't be done with floats. Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/eNDPG/210/

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    Header
</div>
<div id="container">
<span id="leftcol">
     Text1
</span>
<span id="rightcol">
    Text3
</span>  
<div id="centercol">
    Text2
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

#leftcol {
border: 1px solid #0f0;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 200px;
}

#rightcol {
border: 1px solid #0f0;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
width: 250px;
}

#centercol {
border: 1px solid #000;
overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
border: 1px solid pink;
width: 100%;
}

#footer {
border: 1px solid pink;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with CSS `float`. You could use `min-width` property on the wrapper to set a minimum width.

Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <div class="center">Center</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 940px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.center { margin: 0 205px; }

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/eviqet/6/edit)**

**Update:** And here is the **[edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/eNDPG/218/)**

Comment: That works perfect. I just need to make sure the header and footer are in the wrapping container, in order to keep them 100% across the width of the cols.

Comment: Floats are great! However this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
display:table;
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/eNDPG/215/)

Comment: The drawback to this is that the side cols do not maintain a static width.