# CSS , 3 three columns, how to make the middle liquid?

Tags: html, css

The left and right  columns are fixed width: `180px` and `200px` respectively, and the middle column is `liquid`,  expanding to fill the available space.

I don't know how to make the div become column, I used tables before!

Please help.

Comment: google... learn css (display, positioning, box model etc)... try something then get back to stackoverflow for help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/b0d7fn1z/

Comment: Your *question* is not code. Please don't make it harder to read, and therefore harder to help, than it needs to be.

Comment: Have you looked at [How to make 3-Column layout with fluid center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420917/how-to-make-3-column-layout-with-fluid-center-without-floats)?

Comment: This does exactly what you want, and works for fluid layouts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873832/make-a-div-fill-up-the-remaining-width/22719552#22719552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that a [CSS Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/CSS%20Tables) layout works well for this sort of thing. It benefits from [excellent x-browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) and avoids the need to use (and subsequently [clear](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)) floats or having to find a polyfill for the [poorly supported `calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Furthermore, each column is *automatically* the same height.

#### A Simple 3 Column Layout with a Fluid Centre Column:

```
.main {display:table; width:100%;}
.left, .center, .right {display:table-cell;}
.left {width:180px; min-width:180px; background:red;}
.right {width:200px; min-width:200px; background:blue;}
```

Working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/u64xc9x4/

N.B. The `min-width` is optional. Without it the 'cells' can be squished narrower if your page is smaller than the combined column width. This could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
.left{ width:180px; float:left;}

.right{ width:200px; float:left;}

.middle{float:left; width: calc(100% - 380px);}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gd04y1xe) created by @Michael Nguyen

want to learn more than that use google

Comment: good stuff. quick jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/gd04y1xe/

Answer (score 1):

I would use `display: table-cell;` to the center col and `float` property to left and right cols like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z692auyL/

```
.left { 
    background-color: #ddf; 
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 65px;
}
.center{ 
    background-color: green; 
    float: none;
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right{ 
    background-color: cyan; 
    float: right;
    height: 65px;
    width:200px;
}
```